# How to tell Ubuntu to remember I have a UK keyboard?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm running 12.04 and have been since April 2012! All was well, then at some point in the last few weeks I've noticed that Ubuntu seems to think my keyboard has gone American. It hasn't. It hasn't changed at all, neither has anything else*. But now I type quotes @like this@ and don't even ask about my \hashtags

If I go to keyboard layout, everything is set to UK, just as I'd expect. Although there is a blank space by "Input source" on the "System" tab. But it's clearly NOT treating the keyboard as UK.

*the only thing I have changed is to enable auto-login for this user. Surely that should not affect it?

[image: layout 1]

[image: layout 2]

[image: layout 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this a bug, but by adding a US keyboard below the UK one in the Layouts tab of the Keyboard Layout settings window, I can now say "problem solved" #ftw.

[image: screenshot]

Although now I have an annoying "en1" item in the top right menu bar of Gnome Shell.